# Is there any alternative to configSource in applicationHost.config?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, applicationhost, configsource

An ASP.NET site is load balanced using ARR (Application Request Routing) in IIS. The corresponding URL rewriting rule is placed in **applicationHost.config**.

Is there any way to separate this rule in a new config file? The tag `configSource` is no longer supported. I read about `childSource` tag but it is only supported in section.

Here is the rule in **applicationHost.config**:

```
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <globalRules>
                <rule name="ARR_TestFarm_loadbalance" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://TestFarm/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </globalRules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Could this be that it was setup at server level instead of site level?

Comment: what is the reason for needing it in a separate file? might you be able to do what you need with config transforms?

Comment: @AlexanderMeise this settings needs to be done at server level

Comment: @solidau, can you please send me a link about config transforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet what you have going on is a condition in which you want to have different config settings between testing/local development and a production/deploy scenario.

I usually use config transforms to achieve this, and it works quite well. Goes something like this:

Your `app.config` file basically becomes a template. For the example given, yours could look something like the following:

```
...
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <globalRules>
                <rule>
                </rule>
            </globalRules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
...
```

Then, create another file, call it `app.local.config` it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <globalRules>
                    <rule xdt:Transform="Replace">
                        <!-- local rule -->
                    </rule>
                </globalRules>
            </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
...
```

and another file, called `app.release.config`

```
...
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <globalRules>
                <rule xdt:Transform="Replace" name="ARR_TestFarm_loadbalance" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://TestFarm/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
            </globalRules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
...
```

you can find the docs for transforms here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd465326(v=vs.100)

VS has some rules built in on when it transforms the files, but IIRC it is for web.configs only. The addition of FastKoala will allow for app.config transforms and the ability to transform them at build time, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JonDaviswijitscom.FastKoala-WebAppconfigXMLtransforms

Comment: Thank you so much! I will mark it as answer. A quick question: Does transform work for applicationHost.config?

Comment: Not using the FastKoala package as described, no. But you can transform any XML file using the Nuget XmlTransform package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/XmlTransform/) and a build time task. Arguments are documented on the projects GitHub (https://github.com/Novakov/xmltransform)